# Mount a device "invisibly" in Linux

Tags: linux, mount

Is it possible to mount a device or bind mount a file/folder in Linux such that commands like `mount` or `df` don't list the mounted filesystem? If so, how would I achieve this? Would it be as simple as giving a parameter to a command like `mount`, or would it be using a C library function to mount the device, or would I have to find/compile a kernel module in order to mount the device?

Answer (score 4):

No. The commands you're trying to fool get their information from the same kernel data tables that the kernel uses to manage devices.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a container like docker or a Virtual Machine to accomplish this.

The other potential option could be to write to the disk directly, in the same manner that "dd" or "testdisk" does.

With out knowing your end goal, this is the best I can come up with. Though it is worth mentioning that using these methods would not be recommended in 99% of use cases.